# Hausdorff dimension of $X\times X$

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, fractals, hausdorff-dimension

I am thinking of the following question:

Let $X\subseteq \mathbb R$. Is it true that
$$
\mathrm{dim_H}(X\times X)=2\mathrm{dim_H}(X)?
$$

My thoughts:

1. We know that $\mathrm{dim_H}(X)+\mathrm{dim_H}(Y)\leq \mathrm{dim_H}(X\times Y)\leq \mathrm{dim_H}(X)+\mathrm{dim_M}(Y)$ for all metric spaces $X,Y$, where $\mathrm{dim_M}$ denotes the upper Minkowski dimension. Therefore if $\mathrm{dim_H}(X)=\mathrm{dim_M}(X)$, the above is always true.
2. All counterexamples to the equation 
   $\mathrm{dim_H}(X)+\mathrm{dim_H}(Y)= \mathrm{dim_H}(X\times Y)$
   as far as I know use different $X$ and $Y$'s. Is there a counterexample with the same $X$?
3. It is again trivial if $X$ is countable. So we are mainly interested in an uncountable $X$.

Comment: Ever heard of the search button? ;-) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580978/hausdorff-dimension-of-cartesian-product  Also, if you know an example with different $X,Y$ of *the same dimension*, just take $X\cup Y$.

Comment: I searched that question before asking my question. It did not really help me, but yours did.

Comment: For a simple example, see Theorem 5.11 in Falconer's _The Geometry of Fractal Sets_